# Does extensions work if I save chrome page as application into my desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, desktop-application, google-chrome-extension

Does extensions work if I save chrome page as shortcut application?
I've tried but no result.
We know that if we save page as application, there would be no address bar and all other browser buttons.
I've developed simple extension, with no UI, just javascrips running in background.html page. So, as I see no scripts are running in application.
 But I need them work.
What can I do?

Comment: All extensions work for me in saved pages.

Comment: You saved it as Desktop Shortcut Application? Actually : Tools > Create desktop shortcut application ? If I do so, extensions not works.

Comment: Yes. For example if I do this to StackOverflow site and then launch it from the desktop - all extensions that were working on live site are still working (including those with content scripts)

Comment: What about if I want to open options.html page? I'm using extension that automatically hides chrome window to system tray. If I run shortcut application it doesn't go to tray. Even, I have script (in background.html) that alerts dummy message when page is loaded, even it is not working. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Also I have google dictionary extension installed, it is also not works in application mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply edit the shortcut path and append `--enable-extensions`.

[image: properties]

To edit a Windows 7 pinned taskbar item, right click it then right click the program name and select Properties from the menu.

[image]

Comment: I would like to point out that, while this argument might work in general, it does not enable the Google Cast extension such that the extension can be used in application shortcuts...